# Is it expected that DataServiceContext.CreateQuery does not populate ETag?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

In Azure Table Storage I noticed that `DataServiceContext.CreateQuery<T>` does not populate the `ETag` property. Is this expected? Are there any options other then `CreateQuery<T>` that I can use for ad-hoc queries?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using version 2 and above of the storage client library you can use [`ExecuteQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.cloudtable.executequery.aspx) method on the table. Something like below:

```
var table = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient().GetTableReference(tableName);
TableQuery<MyEntity> query = new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableQuery<MyEntity>();
var queryResults = table.ExecuteQuery<MyEntity>(query).Take(5).ToList();
```

`queryResults` will contain the list of `MyEntity` and they will have `ETag` populated.

Comment: Thanks very much! I'll check this out in the morning.

Comment: To add a little more background to Gaurav's answer --- The 1.x clients only supported Tables via DataServiceContext. In this model the entity itself does not track the etag, the context does this for you. In the 2.x client this implementation moved to Table.DataServices namespace and the base entity type is now name TableServiceEntity. 

From 2.x onward there is a new more optimized implementation in the .Table namespace. In this model there is no central context and each entity tracks its own state by exposing an Etag property.

Comment: @kwill So I think I may being doing this wrong. I'm using the 2.x client but am inheriting from `TableEntity`. Are you saying that I should be `TableServiceEntity`?